# Can JavaScript make web-application drag&drop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web-applications

I want to create a web-application that can be drag&drop where ever you want it to make the page your own style. Does anyone one know how can I do this in JavaScript? I'm currently studying JavaScript on my own and then move into HTML5 for video streaming, Java for apps & MySQL, and ColdFusion because someone told me I need it if I want to get my website working on smart-phones.

The only thing I need for ColdFusion because someone told me is for video recording, chat, etc.. to computer users or phone to phone contacts.

Answer (score 3):

[You can use jQuery UI for that.](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/)

Also check out:

- [Drag And Drop Everything With These 30 Handy jQuery Plugins](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/freebies/drag-drop-jquery-plugins/)